# Problem in handling array fetched by graphql-apollo-hooks

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, apollo

I'm querying some data from backend.
I defined Query on back-end, MY_QUERY on front-end and requested by useQuery() with graphql-apollo-hooks.

```
type Query {
  multiA(input: [String]): [typeA]
}

const MY_QUERY= gql`
  query myQuery($input: [String!]) {
    multiA(input: $input) {
      fieldA
      fieldB
    }
  }
`;

const { data, error, loading } = useQuery(MY_QUERY, {
  skip: material === undefined,
  variables: { input: ['inputA', 'inputB'] },
});
```

From graphiql, I defined the query and checked my output data will be something like this.

```
{
  "data": {
    "typeA": [ 
      {
        "fieldA": "!@#$",
        "fieldB": "#$#%",
      },
      {
        "fieldA": "!@#$",
        "fieldB": "#$#%",
      },
      {
        "fieldA": "!@#$",
        "fieldB": "#$#%",
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I checked data by console.log(data.typeA), and it was the same with graphiql.
However, when I access the array, it gets wrong.

In react,

```
console.log(data.typeA)    // result coincidence with graphiql
console.log(data.typeA[0]) // TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

In Chrome console, I saved the result of data.typeA as a global variable, then accessed to array. It works as I expected.

Why I cannot access array in react, whereas I can access array in Chrome console?

Any helps of you would be appriciated. Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the rest of your component code and how you're actually using the query result.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was execution order.
I tried to access array before my data is loaded.
After I moved following code before accessing array,

```
if(loading) return !@#
if(error) return !@#
```

Everything works fine now. Thanks for your helps and sorry for my poor grammar :(